# What are the risks of exposing your institution number/account number/transit number?

Tags: canada, bank-account

In Canada, this information appears to be on all every cheque in your chequebook, what could be done should someone have access to those 3 pieces of information?

I'm asking in regards to whether this information should be encrypted/redacted in a database, or whether its safe to store it plainly.

If someone were to access the information maliciously and glean thousands of these, is that a huge concern?

Answer (score 1):

The latter question (must a database of thousands of entries be protected?) is quite different from the title question.

Of course the database must be protected, because

1. It's much more expensive and time-consuming to clean up compromise of thousands of accounts than a single one
2. In the database case, the decision is not being made by the party most at risk.

A consumer can opt to accept the risk regarding their own account.  A data controller has no right to force the risk on all their users.